# Expand subcomponent rows by default with react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v6

I am using react-table to display some rows, each row has a subcomponent, which just renders some more "subrows." However, you have to click the row in order to show the subrows. React-table does not have a setting to have then expanded by default. There is some discussion out there on doing this but I can't seem to make anything work with my example.

Current looks like this on load:
[image]

After clicking on each row (how im trying to get it to look by default)
[image]

Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import { columns, subComponent } from './tableSetup';


class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactTable data={ data }
        columns={ columns }
        SubComponent={ subComponent }
        expandedRows={ true }
        resizable={ false }
        minRows={ 1 }
        pageSize={ 8 }
        showPageSizeOptions={ false } />
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

tableSetup.js with exampe data
    import React from 'react';

```
export const columns = [
  {
    Header: () => (
      <div />
    ),
    accessor: 'name',
    maxWidth: 300,
    Cell: row => (
      <div className='first-column'>{row.value}</div>
    )
  }
];

export const subComponent = row => {
  return (
    <div>
      {row.original.types.map((type, id) => {
        return (
          <div className='subRow' key={ id }>{ type.name }</div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const data = [
  {
    id: '12345',
    name: 'sports',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'basketball',
        id: '1'
      },
      {
        name: 'soccer',
        id: '2'

      },
      {
        name: 'baseball',
        id: '3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '678910',
    name: 'food',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'pizza',
        id: '4'
      },
      {
        name: 'hamburger',
        id: '5'

      },
      {
        name: 'salad',
        id: '6'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to expand all rows from the beginning, you can use the props `defaultExpanded` in which you give all the rows index you want to expand. (In this case, all of them), like this :

```
  render() {
    // Set all the rows index to true
    const defaultExpandedRows = data.map((element, index) => {return {index: true}});
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          // Use it here
          defaultExpanded={defaultExpandedRows}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          SubComponent={subComponent}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

For more information, you can look [here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/410).

Answer (score 1):

In-order to get multiple sub-rows in react-table v6
1.Firstly make you data Array like this

```
     data = [
            0:{name:'abc', age: 34, friends: [
                        0:{name:'xyz', age: 12, friends:[]}
                        1:{name:'john', age: 45, friends:[]}
                        2:{name:'kim', age: 23 , friends: [
                            0:{name:'ray', age: 15}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
            }
            1:{name:'john', age: 45, friends:[]}
        ]
```

2. Add your subrow key into your react-table

```
    <ReactTable 
                data={data}
                columns={ columns }
                expandedRows={true}
                subRowsKey= {'friends'}
                />
```

3. and then in last step use Expender callback in table columns

```
       columns = [
            {
                Header: "Name",
                accessor: 'name'
            },
            {
                Header: "AGE",
                accessor: 'age'
            },
            {
                Header: "Have Friend",
                Expander: ({ isExpanded, ...rest }) =>
                    {
                      if(rest.original.friends.length === 0) {
                        return null;
                      }
                       else {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            {isExpanded
                                    ? <span>-</span>
                                    : <span>+</span>
                            }
                          </div>
                        );
                      }
                    },
            },
        
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/pjmk93281j?file=/index.js

```js
// all the rows are expanded now
let expandedRows = data.map((i, index) => { index:true }); 

const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(expandedRows);

<ReactTable data={data}
    ...
    expanded={expanded}
    onExpandedChange={(expanded, index, event) => {
        // console.log(index, expanded);
        // don't for get to save the 'expanded'
        // so it can be fed back in as a prop

        console.log(expanded);
        setExpanded(expanded);
    }}
/>
```

Try it, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**In react-table v8 (TanStack) expanding all the rows by default is very easy. We can use the in-built react-table API to achieve it.**

Approach 1

This is the table instance

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<ExpandedState>({});

const table = useReactTable({
data,
columns,
state: {
  expanded,
},

onExpandedChange: setExpanded,
getSubRows: (row: any) => {
  return row.subRows;
},
getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
debugTable: true,
```

});

useEffect(() => {
table.toggleAllRowsExpanded(true); //This will auto expand all the rows by default
}, [data]);

Approach 2

Just pass in the default value of expanded as true as shown below

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<ExpandedState>(true);
```

Both the approaches worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Orlyyn works but I don't understand, why do we need to return an object with index and `true`? Just returning `true` works, and easy to update it later.

```
const defaultExpandedRows = data.map(() => {return true});
```

To make toggle work you can store `defaultExpandedRows` in state and change the value of index to `false` `onExpandedChange`

Comment: How would this work with `subRows`? I have this working for rows, but if there are child rows, they do not expand.